# matlab mplay('fname') play from command line

Tags: matlab, command-line

I can't play AVI files from command line, i want to open few videos and play them all at the same time (need a function like play('all')).

this way i open few videos

'Mplay(filename)'

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following functions to play avi's:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/f3-23960.html#f3-23318

You can also use aviread() and movie() to play avis also. If you want to try this and have problems with it you can look at this for a possible solution:

http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-186ZX/?solution=1-186ZX

Comment: i need play few videos at the same time, no one of this can't open and play at the same time. thanks anywhere

Comment: i can play them only by clicking on play on each one, and this is my problem

Comment: MatLab doesn't support multithread by itself, for something like that I think your best bet would to write a multithreaded app in java/c/c++/ect and convert it to an s-function and implement what you want to do that way.